# Json getting "Undefined" values in my Listbox

Tags: php, mysql, json

The user is required to click on an actor from a actors list. The existing movie titles are removed and then only movies titles pertaining to the chosen actor show.

My "dvdtitle" listbox receives a list of "Undefined" after an actor is chosen. However I checked the response data from `json_encode` function  with `$('#actor').text(data)` to get it visual and I do get correct.

```
[{"503":"Caught In The Crossfire"},
{"690":"Dead Man Running"},
{"1064":"Get Rich Or Die Trying"},
{"1145":"Gun"},{"1254":"Home of The Brave"},
{"2184":"Righteous Kill"},
{"2519":"Streets Of Blood"},
{"3273":"Twelve"}]
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
//getactors.php
include("includes/connection.php");

$q = $_POST['input'];
$final_array = array();

$resultActor = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, plot, catagory, release_date, rated FROM dvd WHERE actors LIKE '%".$q."%' ");

while($rowActor = mysql_fetch_array($resultActor)) {
    $final_array [] = array( $rowActor['id']   => $rowActor['title'] ); 
}

echo json_encode($final_array); 


// JavaScript Document
$('#actorsname').click(function(){

    var actorValue = $('#actorsname option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'getactors.php',
        data: {input: actorValue},
        cache: false,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#dvdtitle option').each(function(i, option) {
                $(option).remove();    // Empty DVD Listbox
            });

            $('#actor').text(data);   //  to visualy check my json Data

            $.each(data, function(i, j) { 
                var row = "<option value=\"" + i.value + "\">" + j.text + "</option>";
                $(row).appendTo("select#dvdtitle");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: you are asking for a property `value` of i which is the index of current element not an object

Comment: @Dalen, Get ready to explain to paislee how that's supposed to help.

Comment: Nico, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php about preventing sql injection.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your Ajax is returning an object containing one key/value pair with the movie ID as a key and the movie title as a value. This makes retrieving the data more difficult because you don't know in the `each` loop which ID to look for.

Ideally, you'd have your JSON formatted this way instead:

```
[
    {"id":503,"title":"Caught In The Crossfire"},
    {"id":690,"title":"Dead Man Running"}
]
```

That would allow you to retrieve the data in your `each` loop using `j.id` and `j.title` because the JSON uses "id" and "title" as keys. But because you don't have it organized that way, you need to loop through each key/value pairs of the object.

**Ideally, you'd want to change your PHP to this:**

```
$final_array[] = array(
    'id' => $rowActor['id'],
    'title' => $rowActor['title']
);
```

And use `j.id` and `j.title` (e.g. var row = `"<option value=\"" + j.id + "\">" + j.title + "</option>";`).

**Here's an example without modifying your PHP code:**
This example is based on your example above. The `data` variable is what's received in your Ajax request.

```
// This is the data retrieved using Ajax.
var data = [{"503":"Caught In The Crossfire"},{"690":"Dead Man Running"},{"1064":"Get Rich Or Die Trying"},{"1145":"Gun"},{"1254":"Home of The Brave"},{"2184":"Righteous Kill"},{"2519":"Streets Of Blood"},{"3273":"Twelve"}];

// Loop through each object in the data array.
$.each(data, function(key, movie)
       {
           // Because the ID is a key and the title a value, we can't determine the ID/title unless we loop through each one of the key/value pairs in the object. Each movie only has one key/value pair so this won't be a problem.
           $.each(movie, function(id, title)
                  {
                      $('<option />').attr('value', id).text(title).appendTo('select#dvdtitle')
                  });
       });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7HGr/

I hope that makes sense.

PS: You may also want to change `$q=$_POST['input'];` to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Hey, is there something painfully obvious I messed up in my answer? I was trying to convey the javascript portion of what you said, but I seem to have faltered at some point.

Comment: @Walkerneo, you had it right. Perhaps you were missing the explanation or like I suggested above, that changing the JSON may be a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried your suggestion example based on my json output however my output in the movie listbox  now shows vertically each letter, quote, periods, and brackets of the data. I will keep trying stuff I guess.

Comment: Just to let you know that when I use the Var Data as you showed your method works nicely.   So why am I getting a vertical output of the data  when I use the same JSON  data?

Comment: I get the same results with Chrome, Firefox and Ie8

Answer (score -2):

`data` is an array of objects. The value of `i` is the index of the object, and `j` is the object.

Here:

```
$.each(x, function(i, j){ 
    $.each(j, function(k, v){
        var row = "<option value=\"" + k + "\">" +v+ "</option>";                
        $(row).appendTo("select#dvdtitle");  
    });   
  });
```

You can see the jquery documentation for more information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: @paislee, I initially told him the problem so he could work on it by himself. I then updated my answer to what he should do.

Comment: the first sentence implies no problem.

Comment: @paislee, I don't understand your dilemma here. The problem is that `data` is an array of objects, so `i` is the index for each object `j` in the array. `i.value` isn't valid javascript, nor is `j.text`. He needs to iterate over each object in the array, then iterate over each key value pair.

Comment: Hinting at an answer doesn't help the OP or anyone who finds this later.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried your suggestion example based on my json output however my output in the movie listbox now shows vertically each letter, quote, periods, and brackets of the data. I will keep trying stuff I guess

Comment: @Nico, Did you do BOTH things that Francois said to do? You were only supposed to do one. Either change the php, or change the javascript, not both.

Comment: @Nico, Please update your question with the code you are currently using. Both PHP and javascript.

Comment: I used $.getJSON   with second example

Comment: $.each(data, function(key, movie)
       {
           // Because the ID is a key and the title a value, we can't determine the ID/title unless we loop through each one of the key/value pairs in the object. Each movie only has one key/value pair so this won't be a problem.
           $.each(movie, function(id, title)
                  {
                      $('<option />').attr('value', id).text(title).appendTo('select#dvdtitle')
                  });
       });

Comment: and this worked  , I dont know why the Ajax call gave me verticle list of all the data.  Thanks alot for your help until next time :)